# Point on the circle by length

Tags: circles

I need to get point on the circle by specified length. For example, there is a circle with radius=1.5 and circumference=9.42. And if I set length=4.71 (half of the circumference), then I should get point on the 180 degrees.

I think I need to convert the length to the radians, but I don't understend how to do that.

[image: image for example].

Currently, it calculates length as radian, but thats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Arch Length = Radius $\times$ Angle in radians

Angle in radians $\theta=\frac{\pi}{180°}\times $Angle in degrees

Comment: It was so obvious. Thanks

Comment: Nice picture! Bye.